# real-time feedback programming with simulink

Tags: matlab, real-time

I'm just getting to know and develop a simple control with MATLAB's real-time windows target.

Basically, the tool supports real-time application developed with Simulink block diagram with just a interface card.

My control application is fairly simple. The pseudo-code can be described shortly as:

```
while (1)
{
if (flg)
{
valve.open();
}

if (pressure > thres_pressure_B) && (flg)
{
valve.off();
wait(5s);
valve.reverse();
flg=0;
}

if (pressure < thres_pressure_A) && (!flg)
{
prog.exit();
}
}
```

with pressure: real-time sensor feedback reading
     valve:    value transmitted to I/O card

where the aim of the control is to vary the pressure (in a container) up from thres_pressure_A to thres_pressure_B and down back to A (similar to a trapezoidal trajectory)

However, I feel difficulty implementing this algorithm in Simulink which is required by the toolbox (real-time windows target)

Is there any way-around this e.g. I can program it with M-file (preferred)? or any Simulink toolbox that can perform the same logic

Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Your code is unclear to me. As soon as the pressure is below `thres_pressure_B` again, the valve is opened again. Will a pressure of `thres_pressure_A` ever be reached?

Comment: @DanielR: thanks! I wasn't very clear about the code but the control is briefly like that